# target="_blank" in form javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, target

but it shows in the main window. Is there any way to open in a new window when click submit button?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function search_navigate() {
var obj = document.getElementById("navbar_search");
var keyword = obj.value;
var dst = "http://smite.guru/stats/" + keyword;
window.location = dst; 
}
</script>

<span id="navbar_form">
<input type="search" placeholder="Search Articles..." id="navbar_search" />
<input type="button" id="navbar_submit" value="Submit" onClick="search_navigate()" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `window.open()` instead of `window.location` [Details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)

> Loads a resource into either a new browsing context (such as a window)
>   or one that already exists, depending on the specified parameters.

```
window.open(dst);
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jg42wfmo/)

Comment: Great. Even you can simply Google it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function search_navigate() {
var obj = document.getElementById("navbar_search");
var keyword = obj.value;
var dst = "http://smite.guru/stats/" + keyword;
window.open(dst); 
}
```

```html
<span id="navbar_form">
<input type="search" placeholder="Search Articles..." id="navbar_search" />
<input type="button" id="navbar_submit" value="Submit" onClick="search_navigate()" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(dst)
```

this will be the best option to open a link in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open(dst,"_blank");` which opens it in a new window